# Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php

i have been working on some application which involves the cURL operation and then Scraping the content of particular URLs.

And there are few computation/calculations following the Scraping.

The issue which i'm facing right now is related to UNDEFINED ARRAY INDEX.

Here are few functions facing  like issues:

{Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\xampp\htdocs\Alps-Phase2\alps\include\alpsOP\scrap-process-request2.php on line 263}

there are more functions similar to these:

```
function getDomainName($objScrap)
 {
try
{
    $result = $objScrap->getDomainName();

    return $result;  //Notice: Undefined offset: 0 
}
catch( Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error in getDomainName !";
    return FALSE;
}

  }

  function getDataForDomainName($objScrap)
  {
try
{
    $result = $objScrap->checkForKeywordInDomain();

    return $result[0];    // Notice: Undefined offset: 0 
}
catch( Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error in getDataForDomainName !";
    return FALSE;
}
 }

function getDensityForDomainName($objScrap){
try
{
    $result = $objScrap->getDomainDensity();
    return $result[0];        // Notice: Undefined offset: 0 
}
catch( Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error in getDensityForDomainName !";
    return FALSE;
}
  }
```

The function definitions for some calls:

```
   function getDomainDensity()
  {
    $result=$this->getDomainName();
    return $this->getKeywordDensity($result);
  }
   function getDomainName()
  {
    preg_match($this->_regExpDomain,$this->_url,$match);

    if($match != NULL)
    return $match[2];
    else
    return array(
    0=> 'Please check URL '.$this->$_url.' [Domain Name]',
    'error' => 'Please check URL '.$this->$_url.' [Domain Name]'
                            );
  }



   function getKeywordDensity(&$subject)
    {
    $splitKeywordCountTotal_len=0;
    $splitKeywordCount = array();
    $resultArray = array();

      for($count_i=0;$count_i<count($this->_keywords);$count_i++)
        {


        $splitKeyword = $this->splitKeyword($this->_keywords[$count_i]);

        $splitKeywordCount=0;
        $splitKeywordCount = $this->prepareResultArray($subject,NULL,$splitKeyword);

        $matchedKeywordCharacterCount=0;
        $f=0;

        foreach ($splitKeywordCount as $val=>$key)
        {
            $splitKeywordCount[$f][2]=strlen($key[0]);

            $splitKeywordCount[$f][3]=$key[1]*strlen($key[0]);
            $matchedKeywordCharacterCount=$matchedKeywordCharacterCount+$splitKeywordCount[$f][3];
            $f++;

        }

        $totalWordsInVisibleContent = $this->getNumberOfWordsInSubject($subject);
        $f=0;
        $totalWordsInVisibleContent_len=0;
        foreach ($totalWordsInVisibleContent as $val=>$key)
        {
            $totalWordsInVisibleContent_len=$totalWordsInVisibleContent_len+strlen($key);
        }

        $splitKeywordCountTotal = 0;
        for($count_j=0;$count_j < count($splitKeywordCount);$count_j++)
        {
            $splitKeywordCountTotal = $splitKeywordCountTotal + $splitKeywordCount[$count_j][1];
            $splitKeywordCountTotal_len = $splitKeywordCountTotal_len + $splitKeywordCount[$count_j][2];

        }

        $resultArray[$count_i]      =   array();
        $resultArray[$count_i][0]   =   $this->_keywords[$count_i];
        $resultArray[$count_i][1]   =   $matchedKeywordCharacterCount/ ($totalWordsInVisibleContent_len);
        $resultArray[$count_i][2]   =   $splitKeywordCountTotal;
        $resultArray[$count_i][3]   =   $matchedKeywordCharacterCount;
        $resultArray[$count_i][4]   =   $totalWordsInVisibleContent;
        $resultArray[$count_i][5]   =   $splitKeywordCountTotal_len;
        $resultArray[$count_i][6]   =   $totalWordsInVisibleContent_len;

    }

    return $resultArray;
}
```

moreover, i plan to run half a million URLs for the same application. If these NOTICES keep on showing up, my application would be facing poor performance.

So guys, need help in resolving the issue.

**** sorry for the drafting of code... new to the forum , dint know how to use the constructs.. :(

Comment: what does `var_dump($result)` show at the points you get those undefined offsets? Either the array doesn't have a `0` key, or it's keyed with something other than integers (e.g. a hash).

Comment: Your array(s) simply do not have an index 0, even though you expect them to. It's a logic error on your part.

Comment: @MarcB hey , the var_dump($result) gives the content of any web site URL we pass on in the function. its basically the response from cURL for the whole web site.

Comment: @deceze so, would u tell me how can i add index [0] to my arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Turn Off Html errors

include the following on the top

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 'Off');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced such an issue just today! I use **PHP7.3.5** and I get the same error, for searching around I found the solution to be:

**Instead of:**

```
try
{
    $result = $objScrap->checkForKeywordInDomain();
    return $result[0];    // Notice: Undefined offset: 0 
}
```

**Change to:**

```
try
{
    $result = $objScrap->checkForKeywordInDomain();

    if(isset($result[0])){
      return $result[0];
   }
}
```

hope this can help anyone `}else{` :).